# React scroll ( стороння библиотека)

Tags: reactjs, dom, прокрутка, library

Как то попытаюсь сформулировать свою проблему. Может кто и поможет.

Насколько я понимаю, *React* не манипулирует напрямую *DOM* и я так же не могу обращаться к тому же *body*.

Соответственно мне нужна какая-то обертка для сайта или приложения (**скажем App**);

В мою задачу входит манипулировать **Scroll-ом** на странице (например во время открытия меню, отключить скролинг).

```
.app {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

или

```
 .app {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
 }
```

Скролл появляется. Но есть но...

Я использую библиотеку **react-scroll** для плавного скролинга и прочего.  Но как только я добавляю подобные  стили для *app*  - **react-scroll** больше не работает.

[Вот ссылка на демонстрацию](https://codesandbox.io/s/usescroll-xm2dvm?file=/src/styles.css:239-302)

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно сделать:

```
import "./styles.css";
import Header from "./Header/Header";
import AboutMe from "./About/About";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const app = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    app.current.style.overflowY = "hidden";
    app.current.style.height = "100%";
    app.current.style.position = "absolute";
    app.current.style.top = 0;
    app.current.style.left = 0;
    app.current.style.width = "100vw";
  }, [app]);

  return (
    <div className="app" ref={app}>
      <Header />
      <AboutMe />
    </div>
  );
}
```